# Does a noun clause as a subject sound natural in modern days?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

President Lincoln wrote, "That I once had the confidence of the people in Sangamon, is sufficiently evident."

Is this type of sentence construct common in today's English usage?

Comment: yes: https://parentingpatch.com/using-noun-clauses-as-subjects/

Comment: No. Modern US president would be highly unlikely to use a construct like that.

Comment: Aside from the comma, I find nothing unusual about the sentence. It's formal, but lots of people (especially presidents—or at least their speech writers) use formal language. To give concrete examples, I would except Obama to say something like that—although not Trump.

Comment: It's perfectly normal usage and quite correct. Perhaps more common in writing or in formal speeches, but it can be used just as well in conversational speech: _That I am happy to be here should be obvious._

Comment: This seems to be a matter of taste. The construction is grammatically correct, and it is not obsolete; to some people it will sound perfectly natural, to some it won't.

Answer (score 1):

*"That I once had the confidence of the people in Sangamon"* is a content clause. Content clauses are noun clauses. They are considered formal or old-fashioned when used as a subject.

However content clauses are commoner as objects/complements and relative clauses and, today, a person would say either

1 "**It** is sufficiently evident that I once had the confidence of the people in Sangamon."

or

2. "**The fact** that I once had the confidence of the people in Sangamon is sufficiently evident."

You will see why "That I once had the confidence of the people in Sangamon" is called a content clause, as it gives the content of the dummy/preparatory "it" and the periphrastic "the fact".

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause